# How to use replit's DB to store message content for multiple users in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm using replit's database to store these keys (also, before I go on I'm making a bot with discord.js), the `notes` key and the `note` key.

I want it so that when the user sends the command of `.note` the notes key's value will get incremented by one and the `note` key's value will add the note that the user creates (`message.content.slice(6)`) so then when I use `.notes` in the channel, I will send the amount of notes the user has(`notes`) and the actual notes themselves(`note`).

I don't really know where to start so could anyone help?

Comment: Do you know how to read and write to the repl.it DB? If not search for the documentation. I'd recommend storing the data as a key value pair where the key is the user's Discord snowflake and the value is an array of their notes

Comment: @Elitezen I want to know how i could first store that message.content.slice(6) and how to use it for multiple users, its pretty big